# Update Score after Collision and Reset at Menu in Pygame

Tags: python, function, pygame

I am working on a very basic 2D runner game in pygame, as a first project. The player has to avoid snails coming across the ground. The player can also stomp on the snails, causing them to respawn.

Right now I am trying to update the score whenever the player stomps on a snail.
I am using the following function to try and update the score whenever a collision happens during gameplay, and then reset the score when the game ends.

```
    def display_score():
    
        if game_active:
            score = 0
            if player_rect.colliderect(snail_rect) and player_rect.bottom <= 448:
                score += 10
            score_surf = score_font.render(f'score: {score}', False, (111,196,169))
        else:
            score = 0
            score_surf = score_font.render(f'score: {score}', False, (111,196,169))
        score_rect = score_surf.get_rect(midbottom = (650,530))
        screen.blit(score_surf,score_rect)
```

Whenever I play the game, the score stays static at 0. I can post code for the whole game if you need more context to figure out the problem.